# Keep arrow close to caption on table header

Tags: css, html-table, flexbox

I have the following table:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: left;
}

.header {
  display: inline-flex;
}
```

```html
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>
          <div class="header">
            <div>&#8592;</div>
            <div>aaaaaaaaa aa</div>
            <div>&#8594;</div>
          </div>
        </th>
        <th>
          <div class="header">
            <div>&#8592;</div>
            <div>bbbbbbbbb bbbbbbbb bbbbbbb</div>
            <div>&#8594;</div>
          </div>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
        <td>bbbbbbb</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

What I want to achieve is to keep the right arrow of each header always close to the caption, even if the text wraps because of window (and table) resize.

This is the situation when table is not resized (and it's ok):

[image]

This is the situation when table is resized (not ok):

[image]

This is what I want when table is resized:

[image]

For the last case I used `flex: 0` on the caption `div`, but this will force text wrap even in the first case, and I don't want it.

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dqtz1wfo/)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by "but this will force text wrap even in the first case"?

Comment: @ArSeN if table as enough space to keep text on a single line for each column header, text will be wrapped, and the first image will be like the last one https://jsfiddle.net/pqkbwdcj/

Comment: You can't do this with css, as soon as you text wraps, the container is 100% width - the duplicate is what is happening with inline block elements instead of words